# How to protect the png from stretching in Android Studio 1.2?

Tags: android, imageview

As shown in the figure,the png is 256*328 pixel,but in the preview of Android Studio,it is as big as the png that I saw in the Windows 7 picture viewer.
I mean that it should be looked more smaller than it was.So how I can makes it as big as 256*328 pixel in my real phone?
Thanks!

http://i4.tietuku.com/a03d2f14cc11fcd0.png

Comment: use wrap content instead of any fix size

Comment: Well,it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First what you're showing us in the picture is not the size of the png. It's the size of the ImageView.

Second it's not pixels(px), it's DP.

Third if you want the picture to have 256*328 pixel just change the xml and replace `dp` with `px`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.And just like what you said,it works :)